# Why does webpack-dev-server not execute compiler hook?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Consider the following `webpack.config.js`. When running `npx webpack` my call to `console.log('Here goes my custom function')` gets executed. However running `npx webpack-dev-server` it does not, although I can see it does the compilation.

Why is that and how can I fix this?

```
module.exports = {
      // ... 
    module: {
      // ...
    plugins: [  
        {
            apply: (compiler) =>{
                compiler.hooks.beforeRun.tap('BeforeRunPlugin', (compilation) => {
                    console.log('Here goes my custom function')
                })
            }
        },
        // ... 
    ],
    devServer: {  
        contentBase: join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: './assets/',
        port: 7700,
        open: false,
        overlay: true, // show compiler errors as overlay
        writeToDisk: true,
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am quoting sokra here, so credits go to him: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10061

> There are two way to run webpack: run and watch. The dev-server uses
>   `watch`.
>
> The `beforeRun` hook is only called for `run` and not for `watch`.
>
> You may want to use the `compile` hook instead.

Comment: Any idea if the have documentation about which hooks get called when?

Comment: I've been stumbling on this for hours now. Thank god for this answer. This doesn't seem covered in Webpack's docs anywhere that I can find.